# Xpath 1.0 using an arithmetic operators

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

Let's say we have this:

```
<a href="www.something/page/1">something</a>
```

Now is there a way to return the @href like: "www.something/page/2". Basically to return the @href value, but with the substring-after(.,"page/") incremented by 1. I've been trying something like

```
//a/@href[number(substring-after(.,"page/"))+1]
```

but it doesn't work, and I don't think I can use

```
//a/@href/number(substring-after(.,"page/"))+1
```

It's not precisely a paging think, so that I can use the pagination, I just picked that for an example. The point is just to find a way to increment a value in xpath 1.0. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
concat(
   translate(//a/@href, '0123456789', ''),
   translate(//a/@href, translate(//a/@href, '0123456789', ''), '') + 1
)
```

So that concatenates the 'href' attribute with all digits being removed with the the sum of 1 and the 'href' with anything but digits being removed.

That might suffice is all digits in your URLs occur at the end of your URL. But generally XPath 1.0 is good at selecting nodes in your input but bad at constructing new values based on parts of node values.

Comment: Thanks, this one looks like it's gonna work, in theory, but it says that I have an invalid expression. Can we actually use those functions as nodes, or as location paths?

Comment: With XPath 1.0 you can select nodes in an input document and you can compute primitive values like strings, numbers or booleans. My suggestion should compute a string value, based on the first `href` attribute found by `//a/@href`. With XPath 1.0 you can't put a function call into a step, like in `//a/@href/concat(...)`, that is only allowed in XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to achieve this, just take the substring after the page, add 1, and then munge it all back together:

This XPath is based on the current node being the `@href` attribute:

```
concat(substring-before(.,'page/'),
       'page/',
       substring-after(.,'page/')+1
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order of operations is a little, well, out of order. Use something like this:

```
substring-after(//a/@href, 'page/') + 1
```

Note that it is not necessary to explicitly convert the string value to a number. From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers):

> The numeric operators convert their operands to numbers as if by
>   calling the number function.

Putting it all together:

```
concat(
    substring-before(//a/@href, 'page/'), 
    'page/', 
    substring-after(//a/@href, 'page/') + 1)
```

Result:

```
www.something/page/2
```